# Extract images from unknown filetype called .gfx

Tags: graphics, export, extract, gaming

I have [this unknown filetype called .gfx](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9395617/zezenia.gfx) (used in a computer game called Zezenia) which I'm pretty certain contain uncompressed flat images (possible .bmp or .png) but I'm not sure how to extract, export or unpack those images.

I've tried things like 7zip, MultiExtractor and so forth without any success.

The size of the file is about 26MB and should contain a few thousand small images/sprites.

How could I extract the images from that file?

Answer (score 0):

do a simple google search for ".gfx" just scan a few result and you should relise that it is some form of graphics file, and since 1 pic USUALLY does not come in a size >5mb, it should obviuously be some form of animation/3d polygon image,

have a look at GNU game development studio, or Game Graphics design software like Vectorworks, Autodesk 123D, here look at this [List of game modeling software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_3D_modeling_software)

hope this helps